# How to make RecyclerView items "pop" in place?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, layout, frontend

I have recycler view that displays LinearLayout "buttons"

I want to display x buttons that fit in recycler without cutting off buttons, and after scrolling if button is cut off it moves up or down so the x buttons are all visible

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I found out. I had to attach [SnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SnapHelper) to my recycler

Code example that im using:

```
public class NHLSnapHelper extends LinearSnapHelper {
private OrientationHelper mVerticalHelper;
private final MainActivity mainActivity = NHLManager.getInstance().getMainActivity();

@Override
public void attachToRecyclerView(@Nullable RecyclerView recyclerView)
        throws IllegalStateException {
    super.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    assert recyclerView != null;
    recyclerView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull View view) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull View view) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int[] calculateScrollDistance(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
    return super.calculateScrollDistance(velocityX, velocityY);
}

@Override
public int[] calculateDistanceToFinalSnap(@NonNull RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager,
                                          @NonNull View targetView) {
    int[] out = new int[2];

    if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
        out[1] = distanceToStart(targetView, getVerticalHelper(layoutManager));
    }
    return out;
}

@Override
public View findSnapView(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
    if (layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
        return getStartView(layoutManager, getVerticalHelper(layoutManager));
    }
    return super.findSnapView(layoutManager);
}

private int distanceToStart(View targetView, OrientationHelper helper) {
    VibrationUtil.vibrate(mainActivity, 10);

    return helper.getDecoratedStart(targetView) - helper.getStartAfterPadding();
}

private View getStartView(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, OrientationHelper helper) {
    if (layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
        int firstChild = ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        boolean isLastItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager)
                .findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == layoutManager.getItemCount() - 1;

        if (firstChild == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION || isLastItem) {
            return null;
        }

        View child = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstChild);

        if (helper.getDecoratedEnd(child) >= helper.getDecoratedMeasurement(child) / 2
                && helper.getDecoratedEnd(child) > 0) {
            return child;
        } else {
            if (((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                    == layoutManager.getItemCount() - 1) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return layoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstChild + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.findSnapView(layoutManager);
}

private OrientationHelper getVerticalHelper(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
    if (mVerticalHelper == null) {
        mVerticalHelper = OrientationHelper.createVerticalHelper(layoutManager);
    }
    return mVerticalHelper;
}

@Override
public int findTargetSnapPosition(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, int velocityX, int velocityY) {
    VibrationUtil.vibrate(mainActivity, 10);
    return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).